# In Custom table always create a new row in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database, controllers, resource-model

I have created a custom table and update data using model and resource model.

But it always create a new row on hitting ajax how to update row as old data is appear.
I think i want to use Update query instead of insert but not have idea where should i change.

My controller file is

```
<?php
namespace Tym17\AdminSample\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Tym17\AdminSample\Model\ReviewsFactory;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $_pageFactory;
protected $reviews;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    ReviewsFactory $reviews,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
{
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->reviews = $reviews;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $reviews = $this->reviews->create();
    $reviews->setData('orderid', $data['order_id']);  
    $reviews->setData('status', $data['payment_status']);  
    if ($reviews->save()) {
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved review'));
    } else {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Review was not saved.'));
    }
}
```

}

My model file path ( app/code/Tym17/AdminSample/Model/ResourceModel/Reviews.php )

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Tym17\AdminSample\Model\ResourceModel;

class Reviews extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
public function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('status', 'id');
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Order to update the record you need to make sure that the Primary field of the table is provided to load the model. If the primary field is set to `null` Magento will create a new record.

Let us assume primary field of your table is named as `id`. Now the updated code will be

```
public function execute()
{
    
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $reviews = $this->reviews->create();
    /* Load record by **id** if it is already available in database*/
    /*if(isset($data['id']) && $data['id'] != null ){
       $reviewsModel = $reviews->load($data['id']);
    }*/
    /* Load record by **Order Id** if it is already available in database*/
    $reviewsModel = $reviews->load($data['order_id'], 'orderid');

    
    $reviewsModel->setData('orderid', $data['order_id']);  
    $reviewsModel->setData('status', $data['payment_status']);  
    if ($reviewsModel->save()) {
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved review'));
    } else {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Review was not saved.'));
    }
}
```

FYI : You can see in your `Model/ResourceModel/Reviews.php` that you have declared an `_construct()` method something like this.

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('table_name', 'primary_field_name');
}
```

Hope it was helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response I have added your code.
My primary field name is id but it still added the the new row for same records.@Abdul

Comment: Any one question is i will not send any $data['id'] so how will it check it database will you please help.

Comment: I have updated my model file as well @Abdul please check

Comment: Assuming Order Id as a unique field in your table, I have updated my answer. Main concept is in order to update a record you need to load the record model either by `load()` or by `collection()`.

Comment: Thanks it solves my issue @Abdul

Comment: will you please help me with this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320997/while-opening-coupon-code-and-trying-to-go-next-page-it-gives-jquery-validate-er question @Abdul

Comment: Most Welcome. Will take a look at your Question. :-)

Comment: Thanks wait for your response on that question @Abdul

Comment: Have you got anything on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320997/while-opening-coupon-code-and-trying-to-go-next-page-it-gives-jquery-validate-er that question @Abdul