# While opening coupon code and trying to go next page it gives Jquery Validate error in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, error, jquery, coupon-codes

I have created some steps between address and payment form in Magento 2.

When i open the coupon code and want to go on next step ( Payment Page Step ) It gives me an error

```
Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined in Jquery.validate.js
```

[image]

How to solve this issue actually i want to default open the coupan code but while trying to go on next page it gives me this error.

I will add coupon code ( phtml file ) with  this on step three and add coupon code in checkout_index_index.xml.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check your log error

Comment: Nothing shows in log files.
I think this is an JS error that's why nothing on the log just a guess when i click on next just a guess will you please help @MohitPatel

Comment: go to network tab and click next button. check your error

Comment: No error on Network and nothing on log just the console error @MohitPatel

Comment: can you possible share your forntend URL??

Comment: Actually currently its on my local didn't setup on Stageing @MohitPatel

Comment: So you Create custom code ?

Comment: Custom code like what i add on my third step to show coupon code ?
Or anything else you would like to ask @MohitPatel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112705/discussion-between-prits-and-mohit-patel).

Comment: As far as i can see without actually looking at the code id say your have 2 fields with the same name/id so it is causing a conflict with the jquery validation plugin

Comment: I have updated a screenshot in my question it shows 2 non unique ID, but how to know which one i have to change and where i want to change will you please help @DavaGordon

Comment: In html ID should always be unique you should never use the same element ID on a page only classes should be duplicated.

Comment: Yupp that i also know and thanks for sharing the info.
but on changing the id of newsletter functionality of that part is not disturbed is it affect any functionality. @DavaGordon please suggest .

Comment: This is very hard to debug without some sort of reference do you have a link?

Comment: Not yet on staging and which setting you are talking about @DavaGordon

Comment: sorry was wrong thread

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112849/discussion-between-dava-gordon-and-prits).