# How to show error message for checkbox on checkout page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation, checkbox, error-message

I have created some steps in Magento 2 and added a checkbox on one step and added required validation for the same.

Validation works perfectly if it is not checked it will not go further but if it is not checked it will not show any error.

[image]

my checkbox code in template is

```
<div class="checkout_usercheckbox">
<input class="required-entry input-checkbox" data-validate="{required:true}" type="checkbox" name="summery_usercheckbox">Accept Terms and Condition
</div>
```

Why it doesn't show error message like to accept term and condition of required.

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: no.you can't. accept term and condition  has a js file to trigger valid when click button place orde file Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/model/agreement-validator.js
you can create file js  catch event when click placeorder button then check checkbox has checked or no.

Comment: Thanks for your response, you mean to say i have to check that in my custom js file right.
So where should i put that code in custom module js file or in theme js file @ThànhTrungTô

Comment: yes.but your file must be called on the checkout page

Comment: how to call my custom file in checkout page is there a way to do that please suggest any post @ThànhTrungTô

Comment: you can reference https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86243/add-custom-js-in-head-in-magento2

Comment: I have added the js file and it shows console but when i add click function on that it doesn't seems to be work will you please check if any issue @ThànhTrungTô

Comment: you can place your custom js inside your phtml and then call that phtml file on checkout page using layout file

Comment: it doesn't work on theme js file because my console are working their and shows but onclick function doesn't work @Chikku

Comment: show your code !

Comment: I have added that in my question if you need anything i will post it out @ThànhTrungTô

Comment: you can try jQuery('#checkout .verify_checkbox'').bind('click', function(){
  //  to do somthing
});

Comment: better you can mixin js file Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default.js 
default, magento will call function placeOrder on here when click place button

Comment: it doesn't work jQuery('#checkout .verify_checkbox'').bind('click', function(){ // to do somthing }); @ThànhTrungTô

Comment: i have to create default.js  in my module @ThànhTrungTô

Comment: yes.you can create default.js in your module.you can mixin default js by requirejs-config.js
you can search mixin js magento 2

Comment: Okk thanks for the info will do that 
will you please help me with https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320997/while-opening-coupon-code-and-trying-to-go-next-page-it-gives-jquery-validate-er question @ThànhTrungTô