# Custom Module for sending mail in Magento 2 didn;t send mail?

Tags: magento2, module, custom, mail

I have created a custom module in Magento 2 for sending the mail but it doesn't send ant mail in my mailbox.

There will be no error shown on page itself please any one help about that.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add files of module to provide better understanding in question.

Comment: Updated my code please check @HamendraSunthwal

Comment: have you checked logs ?

Comment: Just checked Controller Post.php which is form action goes to 302 status code in network.
That's why it doesn't send mail i think @HamendraSunthwal

Comment: check this link :- https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/send-mail-from-custom-module-magento-2/

Comment: Thanks @MohitPatel i have solved my issue with the same link 
Will you please help me with this question i'm stuck from long days but didn't get any solution please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320997/while-opening-coupon-code-and-trying-to-go-next-page-it-gives-jquery-validate-er

Comment: I will add this link in answers??

Comment: yes sure, i will mark it correct @MohitPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link i hope your issue is solve. check below link

**https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/send-mail-from-custom-module-magento-2/**

Any query let me know

**`THANKS.`**