# How to add field value while creating a simple product Programmatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, custom, programmatically, custom-field

I have successfully created simple product Programmatically using magento 2.

But i have created a filed in back end and add that in product but how to fill that data when creating a product.

[image]

I have created my product by

```
$product = $this->productFactory->create();
                $product->setSku($productsku);
                $product->setName($productname);
                $product->setDescription($productname."Description3");
                $product->setShortDescription($productname."Short Description3");
                $product->setWebsiteIds([1]);
                $categories = ["3"];
                $product->setCategoryIds($categories);
                $product->setWeight(1);
                $product->setTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);
                $product->setVisibility(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH); // To make product visible in both catalog,search
                $product->setPrice($p);
                $product->setAttributeSetId(4); // Attribute set for products
                $product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
                $product->setUrlKey($productsku);
                $product->setStockData(
                    array(
                        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                        'manage_stock' => 1,
                        'is_in_stock' => 1,
                        'qty' => 1
                    )
                );
                $product = $this->productRepository->save($product);
                $product->save();
```

Like i have to add some custom data while creating a product Programmatically.How to do that ?

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more information regarding the creation of the product so we can better understand the method in which you are using e.g. API / Patch / Install Data

Comment: Updated my product create code please check @DavaGordon

Comment: You shouldnt really use custom_data as a attribute code as getCustomData is a reserved function. but you should be able to set your data value using setCustomAttribute('myattribute', $value); or setMyattribute($value);

Comment: Thanks for the response i have changed that no problem will try and update you @DavaGordon

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly @DavaGordon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom attributes values in magento 2 can be set and retrieved by

**Getting Value**
getCustomAttribute('myattribute')->getValue() / getMyattribute()

**Setting Value**
setCustomAttribute('myattribute', $value); / setMyattribute($value)

Comment: By using getCustomAttribute i will get 
Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValue Object
(
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [attribute_code] => custom_price_value
            [value] => 99
        )

)
How do i will get value ?@Dave

Comment: please see my answer i have updated it you can see from your output the value is 99 so just format it like so getCustomAttribute('custom_price_value')->getValue()

Comment: It works perfectly Thanks @Dave
will you please help me with this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320997/while-opening-coupon-code-and-trying-to-go-next-page-it-gives-jquery-validate-er question