# How to get product custom attribute by using sku or ID in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, custom-attributes, sku, id

I have created a custom attribute for product in Magento 2.

But how to get that value by sku or id in Magento 2 ?

I have got the product id by

```
$product = $this->productRepository->get($productsku);
$id = $product->getEntityId();
```

**how to get custom attribute value if my attribute name is 'my_custom_attribute'**
[image]

Comment: where you want to get product attribute ?

Comment: Thanks for your response I want it in a controller file @Pawan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add field value while creating a simple product Programmatically in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/321842/how-to-add-field-value-while-creating-a-simple-product-programmatically-in-magen)

Comment: Yes it works thanks @DavaGordon

Answer (score 0):

This is how i get a custom attribute from a product

```
use \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory

$product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($id);
$value_code =  $product->getAttributeText($attr);
```

Hope this can help you